# Bug output feature class

Tags: python, arcmap

I just encounter a little bug, maybe someone can help me.

I'm creating Thiessen Polygons.

I define my shapefile in Input Features, and in Output Feature Class, then I have to possibilities either keep the default file or save my output where I want.

When I save my output in the Default file, and then I open the attribute table of the Polygon file created, I can observe the Shape_length field and the Shape_Area field.

But if I save my file in another file (Output Feature Class), then I don't find the Shape_length field and the Shape_Area field in my attribute table..

I have no idea how to change that? because I'm running a small loop using Python and I'd like to have the Area for each Polygon in the table rather than having to recalculate it for each file created !

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER: In order to avoid the bug describe before, one needs to set up the default geodatabase.

Forthat you can check this link:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sn0000000t000000.htm

Comment: This doesn't read like an answer to the question. Are you trying to add new info to your question, or are you trying to answer it? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Saving the output in a file geodatabase (which is probably what your default output location is) will create a feature class, which by default adds the shape_length and shape_area columns.  Saving the output into a regular folder will create a shapefile, which does not create these fields by default.  If your python script requires you to place your outputs in different places and in different formats, you could check to see if your output will be into a regular folder, and thus a shapefile, and add the two fields accordingly, then calculate them.

This is not a bug, it's a format thing.